# this ex of K&R ch3 is wrong?

Tags: c

code like this,in page 44.

int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while(low <= high){
        mid = (high+low)/2;
        if(x < v[mid]){
            high = mid + 1;
        }else if(x > v[mid]){
            low = mid + 1;
        }else{
            return mid;
        }
        printf("mid is %d\n",mid);
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int v[] = {2,3,4,7,8,23,54,65,76};
    int ret = binsearch(7, v, sizeof(v)/sizeof(int));

    printf("%d,ret is %d\n", sizeof(v),ret);
    return 0;
}

compile and run it,dead loop as a result! so the line "low = mid + 1;" should take as "low = mid;", is that right?thx.

Comment: low=mid will just retain the infinite loop. one implied requirement of a binary search is that each iteration changes the start/end point of the zone being considered. if you don't change the goalposts properly, you'll either fail the search, or go infinite loop.

Comment: I really doubt you having made a mistake copying rather than K&R having mistake in Binary Search.

Comment: @fayyazkl no,the code adhere is same as the book shows.

Comment: @MarcB at least,"low=mid" in this ex works.

Comment: @jiych.guru You really made me grab my copy. Tell you what, it is K&R second edition. Chapter 3 on control flow. There is no binary search on page 44. Rather it is on 58 (probably difference in edition. The if block in book is if(x<v[mid]) high = mid - 1. The same as the correct answer below.

Comment: The reason is editable(no-scanned) ebook may type manually and might consist of typo. I just found the same typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in the code you posted is not the value of `low`, but in the test for the setting of the value of `high` ... if `x` is less than `v[mid]`, then the new index value of `high` should be one less than, not greater than `mid`.  So you want to change the following:

```
if(x < v[mid]){
    high = mid + 1;
```

to:

```
if(x < v[mid]){
    high = mid - 1;
```

You can see a working example here: http://ideone.com/E6Ma8

Comment: yeah,i take a look at a data struct book,you're right.i knew that,thx.